# Is there a cheat sheet for TeXstudio keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

Lately I'm using TeXstudio a lot more and I'm having trouble to get used to the default keyboard shortcuts. There are a lot and the dialog to search them is not exactly user-friendly.

So my question is if there's something like a cheat sheet that lists the most important keyboard shortcuts in TeXstudio. Ideally it should be printable, so I can print it and place it on my desk.

I tried searching for a keyboard shortcut map but to no avail.

---

If you're not familiar with the concept of a cheat sheet for keyboard shortcuts: [Here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) is one for the IntelliJ IDE as an example.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I took my own advice.. Here's a list of all of the default TeXstudio shortcuts (hopefully I did not miss anything out..). It's not the nicest thing in the world, but at least it's a starting point.

[image: updated cheat sheet]

I'll just share the `.tex` file [here](https://pastebin.com/TTpS9fGF), if you want the `.pdf` just compile it yourself.

**Disclaimer:** It's far from perfect, and I intend to touch up on it sometime in the future, when I have more time.  (Not now! Unless there is some serious mistake, I won't be coming back to this till sometime later.)

I also do not guarantee that this is the best way to go about doing this, since I am *not at all* experienced with typesetting tables in LaTeX. `:p`

Comment: Sorry if this reference is Windows specific. I'm not familiar with Mac shortcuts as I don't have one. Presumably it's just `Cmd` instead of `Ctrl` everywhere..

Comment: This is awesome! Sharing LaTeX source file is truly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Within the options you'll find "Shortcuts" with the default one. For printing you would have to make screenshots (and TeX them together).

[image: shortcuts]

Comment: Thanks for great advice (and help)!

Answer (score 2):

Modified Troy's list of shortcuts to simplify the LaTeX, and use the flexibility of longtable and the leaflet class.  This version should be easier for you all to extend and maintain.  Download the pdf and tex source via  https://profajroberts.github.io/LaTeX/Share/TeXstudioShortcutsV1.3a.zip

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show your code in your answer, do not use an external link which can break ...