# How to find and change keyboard shortcuts effectively in TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, keyboard

**This question is based on a misunderstanding due to a bug in TeXStudio:** There should be a warning when you use a key-combination that has already been used. However, this warning may be absent when for some reason two different parameterizations of the same key are detected. This happens for example for `CTRL+SHIFT+^` vs `CTRL+SHIFT+6`. Make sure to use the latter form by typing it in by hand (rather than the automatical detection which strangely does not result in the format used by the rest of TeXStudio). (See my answer for more details.)

---

When I wanted to change some keyboard shortkeys in TeXStudio I ran into some trouble. I started changing some shortcuts to combinations that I liked, hoping/thinking that if I would use a combination that was already in use TeXStudio would warn me what other key already uses that combination. It seems that TeXStudio has no such check leading to problems with combinations that are used multiple times. In addition it seems that TeXStudio has no way to search through the shortcuts by key combinations. Since there are thousands of shortcuts it would take forever to find the doubles. Did I overlook a way to search by key combination? Is there some other solution?

---

I am interested in finding the actions the key bindings had been bound to by default in order to remove those (not my new ones) so that I can replace them with my own.

Answer (score 4):

As you have noticed

> TeXStudio would warn me what other key already uses that combination.

So now we have numerous problems and you could simply delete the ini file, thus loosing ALL customisation including all the key changes. That would be the best advise to give when someone has ignored all the previous warnings. However:-

You know you can change each key back to its default, one by one like this.

[image]

Knowing **they are stored in the TeXstudio.ini** file like this

**[image: strong text]**

The simplest bulk solution **WITHOUT TeXstudio active** (otherwise it will save the unwanted customisation again), is to simply delete all those rogue entries keeping as few as is possible.

[image]

Comment: thanks! I could have been more clear in my question however, the main point is to find out what the keys were previously bound to so that I can remove those. (I had not made many changes yet so I would not really have had a problem with going back to the defaults everywhere). I don't understand the first part you quoted and the part about ignoring previous warnings. Are you saying that normally TeXStudio does give warnings that you think I ignored? In my case there definitely were no warnings.

(Your information is still great to know too, by the way. Thanks!)

Comment: To solve my actual question: Is there a similar simple text document containing the default "keysettings" just like there is for the custom one?. With that it seems that worst case I can search for the key combinations that I am interested in with other tools (such as a simple grep on the command line).

Comment: reference first comment If no warnings that should indicate that they had not been assigned in editor however they could of course be reserved by the system, or by you with windows hot keys  or even another  application, in which case the editor could not necessarily know. re second comment I do appreciate it is not easy to check what has been assigned you need the cheat sheet at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365456/is-there-a-cheat-sheet-for-texstudio-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, in this case one of the keys I tried to rebind was CTRL+SHIFT+6 which by default is "Toggle Bookmark". I now found it in the list I removed that binding but strangely enough now nothing happens when I try even though I have superscript bound to this key combination.

Comment: I am finding that even though I cleared the bookmark binding that key combination still cannot be used for something else. Other custom bindings work.

Comment: I see edit > Toggle Bookmark as blank (can't be assigned ?) the first entry for an unnamed bookmark is Ctrl+Shift+B which II can change to Ctrl+Shift+F6 as not currently assigned Am I looking at similar entries It may be possible to set one key combination in editor and another in say viewer ?

Comment: thanks for thinking along! I found the problem. The issue was that in the shortcut menu when I entered my key combination it was detected as CTRL+SHIFT+^ instead of CTRL+SHIFT+6. Clearly in the editor itself the combination got interpreted only as CTRL+SHIFT+6 and so nothing happened. (That is a dangerous discrepancy for TeXStudio to have.)

( I think I should ask and answer a separate question on this for the sake of posterity, since this now has little to do with my question.)

Comment: Yes Ctrl+Shift+6 is assigned to bookmark 6 so I do get warning but misread as your desire to use F6 (my bad)

Comment: So it may be partly keyboard related as some keyboards have a different way of handling ^ versus 6 but up to now I was unaware that it is possible to "double-up" accidentally by cut and paste entry rather than key press only

Comment: Yes it might be keyboard related but then it is still very strange note that I did not double-up by using cut and paste. I used automatic detection also in the menu. It just gets detected differently whether you are in the menu or in the editor (both within TeXStudio).

Comment: It does look like a bug with the shifted numerals {top row} since using ctrl+shifted ^ should have been assigned as the default for toggle bookmark 6 (ctrl+shift+6) so what about the others like hyphen and =

Comment: looking at my other alternatives they seem to be ok (unassigned) but I could accidentaly have put shift+ and shift= without noticing via long hand although I get invalid when trying alt+shift+ by key press e.g. I can manually enter ctrl+shift+= but that may not be recognised since it should be ctrl+shift++

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there actually is a warning system when you assign a key combination twice. What happened here is that I assigned a new binding by pressing the key combination. But for keys involving shift there are two interpretations for every key combination. In my case it detected `CTRL+SHIFT+^`. This combination was free and so no warning was given. However the combination `CTRL+SHIFT+6` was taken by Toggle Bookmark. Of course this combination actually corresponds to the same keys, but it appears that in the option menu one interpretation is used, while in the editor the other is used. The solution is to set the key combination in the menu more carefully by hand (not by pressing the buttons) to the combination where the default symbol (not the top one, activated by shift) is used.

So there is no need to search the existing bindings by key combination. One can just try a desired combination and if it is already in use you will receive a warning.